# WPF xaml DataTrigger binding not working

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, binding, datatrigger

I have created a simple application using xaml and C# which binds the border color to the code behind boolean method `IsToday`. But somehow it's not working.

Can somebody help please? I've tried `INotifyPropertyChanged` as well but it doesn't work. Grateful if someone could help, thanks!

Code behind:

```
namespace WpfApplication3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            IsToday = true;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public bool IsToday { get; set; }
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml">
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
        <Grid>
        <Border Style="{StaticResource Highlight}">
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

XAML Dictionary

```
 <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
        <Style TargetType="Border" x:Key="Highlight">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsToday}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsToday}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just set the context from xaml.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <!-- your code -->
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to set `DataContext` for your `Window`:

```
 public MainWindow() {
      InitializeComponent();
      DataContext = this;
      IsToday = true;
 }
```

Of course this works just ***initially***, every changes made to `IsToday` after that won't work. As you know we have to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged`.